# Re-routing a Component without Reloading Entire Page

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I have a React+Django app which is a custom video player, and I'm currently working on a related videos / queue at the end of the video. I have it working, if I use a simple `window.location.replace` with the link to the next video. However, it would be a lot smoother to only reload the video player.

From the many many threads I've read on SO, it seems that this it is possible to re-route my "main" component within a child component in React, but none of the methods have worked for me and I have a slightly different case than everything I've read. If the video playing depends on my URL (or Route), is it even still possible to reload without re-rendering the entire page?

Here's a barebones version of the relevant code:

**Index.js:**

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <App/>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

const element = <Welcome/>;
ReactDOM.render(
    element,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

**App.js:**

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Row id="app-container" className="h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/app/:number' component={Player}/>
                </Switch>
            </Row>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

**Queue.js,** Note: this is obviously just the part I'm having trouble with. I have clickable imgs to do the `window.location.replace` method.

```
<div>
 <Link to='app/1' replace>
  Previous Video
 </Link>
<div>
```

The `Link` actually does change the URL in the way I want, but doesn't reload the App. I've spent a long time trying to implement solutions to this problem from other SO posts, but I'm worried that once I get it, it will end up forcing the whole page to reload anyway. Can anyone tell me if it's possible to JUST re-reroute my app? It's alright if the URL doesn't change, as long as the app is based on the new route.

Thanks in advance